# Distinguishing the user action causing a view controller to be pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm subclassing `UINavigationController` and want to in order to add the ability to add previously popped view controllers *back onto the stack*, akin to a forward button in a  web browser.

When the user presses a button, I want to add the most recently popped off view controller back onto the stack. I do this by getting the view controller at the top of my custom stack, and calling `pushViewController:animated:` with it.

In the case where taps on a table view cell or something to go forward a new way into the view hierarchy, I want to clear my "popped view controllers" stack. Similar to how if the user clicks on a new link in a web browser the "forward" history is cleared.

This is where my issue lies. I don't know how to differentiate between when I call `pushViewController:animated:` in order to restore a view controller, and when the user taps a cell to push one. In the latter case, I want to clear my stack, but in the former I don't want to.

I can't figure out what to do here. In a perfect world `pushViewController:animated:` would have `userOptions:` parameter or something on it that would allow me to distinguish between how it's being used, but unfortunately that parameter doesn't exist.

Such an issue must come up rather frequently. How would I deal with it in this case? How would I differentiate between the circumstances in which the method is being called?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the obstacle is here. You should be in control of when `pushViewController:animated` is being called; you can do other things beforehand. When the button is pressed, do one thing in its action method. When a table view cell is selected, do the other thing in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. What am I missing?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I want this to be a simple, drop-in `UINavigationController` replacement. If I have to go into every class and call custom methods instead of the ones used by every `UINavigationController`, it's much less clean.

Comment: I see. I think something along the lines of CRD's answer is going to have to be the way you go, then. I don't see any way around having a special "go foward" method for the button.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly one common approach to doing this is:

1. Your "goForward" method should call your superclass' `pushViewController:animated:`
2. Override `pushViewController:animated:` to call both your superclass' `pushViewController:animated:` and your "clearStack" method.

Comment: For `2.`, my issue is that `pushViewController:animated:` is called during a segue automatically. And I don't want to put my `clearStack` method in there as it would be called each time a segue happens. I don't know how to inject my own method in there.

Comment: If the method is called on an instance of your class then your override gets called, it doesn't matter who makes the call, that is a core feature of inheritance.

Comment: If literally all I'm doing is creating a drop-in replacement for `UINavigationController`, how do I make the `goForward` method only call the super? Is the `goForward` method not `pushViewController:animated:`?

Comment: The `goForward` method is the action method for your go forward button. You call a method on your superclass using `[super ...]` (as opposed to say `[self ...]`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you need two different methods in your subclass. One for the case where you want to restore a view controller, and one where you want to clear the stack. Both will perform some custom logic and call `pushViewController:animated:` on `super`.

Comment: But doesn't `pushViewController:animated:` get called by a segue automatically? How do I inject my own method there?